# VBA not releasing COM component memory ( built in C#)

Tags: c#, vba, com, interop

created COM component in C# and called it in VBA. 
VBA Code:

Sub test()

```
For i = 1 To 1000
    Dim p As ClassLibrary1.Point
    Set p = New ClassLibrary1.Point
    Dim surface As ClassLibrary1.surface
    Set surface = New ClassLibrary1.surface
    Debug.Print surface.Create(p)
Next i
```

End Sub

ClassLibrary1 consists of a DLL and a TLB (which I reference in my VBA)

ClassLibrary1 has classes and respective interfaces for Point and Surface.
When I run this, Excel causes an increase in memory (as seen from Windows Task Manager)
of 700KB (approx) and every time I run this, it increases and remains constant.

I tried setting the objects to 'Nothing' but it doesnt help. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use 1000, use a billion.

Comment: I get your point Hans. Same thing as below. My program levelled out at 87k in Mem usage and stayed constant after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't actually have a problem the task manger reports the [Working Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684891%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> The working set of a program is a
>   collection of those pages in its
>   virtual address space that have been
>   recently referenced. It includes both
>   shared and private data. The shared
>   data includes pages that contain all
>   instructions your application
>   executes, including those in your DLLs
>   and the system DLLs. As the working
>   set size increases, memory demand
>   increases.

You might want to see what the private bytes are which represent the actual memory that you are using. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/09/06/742568.aspx) from Tess Ferrandez

Comment: Thanks a lot!! And your explanation is dot on! Thanks again.